# Update graph from json data

Tags: javascript, json

I got a go program that outputs json data:

```
{ "cpu" : { 
      "Idle" : 9875425,
      "Iowait" : 28338,
      "Irq" : 5,
      "Nice" : 9707,
      "Softirq" : 4051,
      "System" : 153933,
      "Time" : 1329211407,
      "User" : 392229
},
"cpu0" : { 
      "Idle" : 2417441,
      "Iowait" : 3212,
      "Irq" : 5,
      "Nice" : 1419,
      "Softirq" : 3935,
      "System" : 62177,
      "Time" : 1329211407,
      "User" : 109227
    },
}
```

I'm looking for a good efficient way to present and update a graph using javascript (say for every 1s).

Comment: What javascript graph library are you using if any?

Comment: I have looked at flotr which looks like what I need.

Comment: What sort of graph (pie, bar, ...)? And how complex is the design? If not too complex it's easily achieved by just setting a css value (e.g. height) on some DOM elements, avoiding canvas/svg based js graphing libraries.

Comment: Graphs of this can be created with https://www.koia.io.<br>
Koia uses D3.js under the hood. <br>
The source code is on https://github.com/centeractive/koia

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no shortage of javascript libraries to graph data. I've worked with [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/), which is free for personal projects. To make a graph using your data in highcharts, you could do something like this:

```
var data = [] //your data from above; you'll need to convert it to an array of y-values or one of the other available formats

var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            defaultSeriesType: 'line',
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Series Title',
            data: data
        }]
    });
});
```

...However, as mentioned, there are lots of JS graphing libraries. To name a few:

- [JQPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/)
- [D3](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/)
- [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/)
- [Sencha Charts](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/)

If you're looking for a more specific answer, I'm not sure folks can offer that much in response to a vague question.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a big fan of [dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com/). Very powerful.  Very flexible.

Answer (score 4):

I like to work with the d3js library for this kind of work.

http://mbostock.github.com/d3/

It has very nice functions to update graphs with new data.

Maybe you can base your work on the "bullet charts" example.

Answer (score 3):

Google has a **BUNCH** of apis. You should check some of them out. One of them is the chart api [here](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/). It let's you make QR codes too. Google even has some examples in the js playground: http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#annotated_time_line